# Problem making an svg button fully clickable due to other objects nearby

Tags: html, css, svg

First of, i have made a nearly identical question before, and the problem was fixed (at the time).
I'm making a buttons panel using multiple in-line svgs. All of them work perfectly and have been position just where i want them, but this has render my central (home) button parcially ineffective.
Basically, the top half works great and the bottom one is NOT clickable (i'd like to solve this). 
The bounding box of another button runs through that area, though it is not visible. This is the same problem i fix before, by appliying a circle clip path to the home button, but for some reason this doesn't work anymore.

Below i leave a piece of html with the svgs and relevant divs. You'll also find my css data, which shows how was all positioned and what kind of clip paths are active.
PS: Sorry for long code, i'm new and don't know how much info you need.

```css
#brand{
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: circle(50%);
}
#reserve{position: absolute;}
#services{margin: auto;}
#faq{margin: auto;}
#login{margin: auto;}
#destinies{margin: auto;}
@media screen and (min-width: 751px){
#wide-interface{
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
#brand{
 width: 9.5%;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 2.6%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#reserve{
 width: 83%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 top: 12%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#faq{
 width: 20%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 1%
}
#header{padding-bottom: 5%;}
#login{
 width: 20%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#services{
 width: 28%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: -3%;
}
#destinies{
 width: 28%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-left: -3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wide-interface">
    <div id="top-buttons">
 <div id="services">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 291.47 59.96"><defs>
 <style>.cls-3{fill:#ffffff;}</style>
 </defs><a xlink:href="services.html"><path class="cls-3" d="M0,0V42.09A17.81,17.81,0,0,0,17.81,59.91L258,60c1.27-23.16,12.07-42.66,33.48-59.9ZM76.15,37.75a7.42,7.42,0,0,1-3.22,2.5,13.09,13.09,0,0,1-5.22.94,19.78,19.78,0,0,1-5.06-.65,12.32,12.32,0,0,1-4-1.72l2-4.48A12.76,12.76,0,0,0,64,35.88a13,13,0,0,0,3.74.58c2.33,0,3.5-.58,3.5-1.75a1.46,1.46,0,0,0-1-1.37,18.22,18.22,0,0,0-3.2-.93A30.42,30.42,0,0,1,63,31.29a6.83,6.83,0,0,1-2.8-1.92A5.17,5.17,0,0,1,59,25.81a6.16,6.16,0,0,1,1.07-3.55,7.3,7.3,0,0,1,3.21-2.5,13.24,13.24,0,0,1,5.23-.92,18.27,18.27,0,0,1,4.17.48,13.13,13.13,0,0,1,3.63,1.39l-1.88,4.52a12.43,12.43,0,0,0-5.95-1.66,5,5,0,0,0-2.64.54A1.6,1.6,0,0,0,65,25.5a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1,1.29,17.91,17.91,0,0,0,3.16.89,29.55,29.55,0,0,1,4.07,1.12A6.92,6.92,0,0,1,76,30.7a5.1,5.1,0,0,1,1.19,3.55A6,6,0,0,1,76.15,37.75Zm21.12,3H80V19.27H96.87V24H86v3.62h9.55v4.54H86v3.93H97.27Zm16.66,0L110,35.05h-3.31v5.71h-6.08V19.27h9.82a12.2,12.2,0,0,1,5.07,1A7.47,7.47,0,0,1,118.84,23,7.55,7.55,0,0,1,120,27.22a7.55,7.55,0,0,1-1.09,4.07A7.4,7.4,0,0,1,115.8,34l4.64,6.76Zm22,0h-6l-9.18-21.49h6.57l5.83,14,6-14h6Zm16.54,0H146.4V19.27h6.08Zm10.11-7.54a5.31,5.31,0,0,0,2.12,2.16,6.16,6.16,0,0,0,3.11.77,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,5.07-2.52l3.86,3.5a10.11,10.11,0,0,1-3.93,3,12.89,12.89,0,0,1-5.3,1,12.74,12.74,0,0,1-6.07-1.43,10.71,10.71,0,0,1-4.22-4A11,11,0,0,1,155.7,30a11,11,0,0,1,1.53-5.77,10.76,10.76,0,0,1,4.22-4,12.74,12.74,0,0,1,6.07-1.43,12.89,12.89,0,0,1,5.3,1.05,10.08,10.08,0,0,1,3.93,3l-3.86,3.5a6.36,6.36,0,0,0-5.07-2.51,6.26,6.26,0,0,0-3.11.76,5.34,5.34,0,0,0-2.12,2.17,7.22,7.22,0,0,0,0,6.41Zm34.11,7.54H179.45V19.27H196.3V24H185.47v3.62H195v4.54h-9.54v3.93H196.7Zm19.37-3a7.42,7.42,0,0,1-3.22,2.5,13.16,13.16,0,0,1-5.22.94,19.91,19.91,0,0,1-5.07-.65,12.51,12.51,0,0,1-4-1.72l2-4.48a12.84,12.84,0,0,0,3.34,1.54,13.06,13.06,0,0,0,3.75.58c2.33,0,3.5-.58,3.5-1.75a1.47,1.47,0,0,0-1-1.37,18.39,18.39,0,0,0-3.21-.93,31.31,31.31,0,0,1-4-1.12,6.87,6.87,0,0,1-2.79-1.92,5.18,5.18,0,0,1-1.17-3.56A6.17,6.17,0,0,1,200,22.26a7.21,7.21,0,0,1,3.2-2.5,13.32,13.32,0,0,1,5.24-.92,18.27,18.27,0,0,1,4.17.48,12.94,12.94,0,0,1,3.62,1.39l-1.87,4.52a12.46,12.46,0,0,0-5.95-1.66,5,5,0,0,0-2.64.54A1.58,1.58,0,0,0,205,25.5a1.38,1.38,0,0,0,1,1.29,17.65,17.65,0,0,0,3.16.89,30,30,0,0,1,4.07,1.12A7.06,7.06,0,0,1,216,30.7a5.09,5.09,0,0,1,1.18,3.55A6.1,6.1,0,0,1,216.07,37.75Z"/><path class="cls-3" d="M110.09,24.06h-3.37v6.29h3.37a4.28,4.28,0,0,0,2.83-.81,2.9,2.9,0,0,0,1-2.32,2.94,2.94,0,0,0-1-2.33A4.23,4.23,0,0,0,110.09,24.06Z"/></a></svg>
 </div>
 <div id="faq">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 209.09 59.79"><defs><style>.cls-4{fill:#ffffff;}</style></defs><a href="faq.html"><path class="cls-4" d="M124.63,27.62a6.49,6.49,0,0,0-.75-3.15,5.36,5.36,0,0,0-2-2.12,5.92,5.92,0,0,0-5.77,0,5.36,5.36,0,0,0-2,2.12,6.49,6.49,0,0,0-.75,3.15,6.42,6.42,0,0,0,.75,3.14,5.3,5.3,0,0,0,2,2.12,5.86,5.86,0,0,0,5.77,0,5.3,5.3,0,0,0,2-2.12A6.42,6.42,0,0,0,124.63,27.62Z"/><polygon class="cls-4" points="82.78 29.66 88.19 29.66 85.48 22.92 82.78 29.66"/><path class="cls-4" d="M35.82,0C14.44,17.22,1.3,36.68,0,59.79l155.46.11A63.86,63.86,0,0,1,209.09.8V0ZM63.88,21.69H53.32v4.63h9.3v4.61h-9.3v7.22h-6V17.09H63.88ZM71,37.46a3.59,3.59,0,0,1-4.89,0,3.5,3.5,0,0,1,0-4.88,3.72,3.72,0,0,1,4.92,0,3.57,3.57,0,0,1,0,4.88Zm20.62.69-1.65-4.09H81l-1.65,4.09H73.3l9.3-21.06h5.86l9.33,21.06ZM105,37.46a3.59,3.59,0,0,1-4.89,0,3.53,3.53,0,0,1,0-4.88,3.44,3.44,0,0,1,2.46-.93,3.39,3.39,0,0,1,2.46.93A3.24,3.24,0,0,1,106,35,3.29,3.29,0,0,1,105,37.46Zm24.16,5.1a8.08,8.08,0,0,1-3.32.68,9.62,9.62,0,0,1-6-1.94,25.31,25.31,0,0,1-3.2-2.91,11.68,11.68,0,0,1-4.88-2,10.55,10.55,0,0,1-3.32-3.8,10.75,10.75,0,0,1,4.51-14.56,13.49,13.49,0,0,1,12,0,10.54,10.54,0,0,1,5.7,9.54,10.57,10.57,0,0,1-7.16,10.17,3.84,3.84,0,0,0,1.19.93A3,3,0,0,0,126,39a4.35,4.35,0,0,0,3.19-1.47l2.58,3.07A6.9,6.9,0,0,1,129.16,42.56Z"/></a></svg>
 </div>
 <div id="login">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 209.09 59.79"><defs><style>.cls-5{fill:#ffffff;}</style></defs><a href="login.html"><path class="cls-5" d="M97.83,24.58a6,6,0,0,0-5.89,0,5.57,5.57,0,0,0-2.09,2.16,7.16,7.16,0,0,0,0,6.42,5.57,5.57,0,0,0,2.09,2.16,6,6,0,0,0,5.89,0,5.5,5.5,0,0,0,2.09-2.16,7.08,7.08,0,0,0,0-6.42A5.5,5.5,0,0,0,97.83,24.58Z"/><path class="cls-5" d="M173.27,0H0V.8A63.85,63.85,0,0,1,53.63,59.9l155.46-.11C207.8,36.68,194.65,17.22,173.27,0ZM82,40.69H65.67V19.21h6.08V35.87H82Zm23.28-5a10.87,10.87,0,0,1-4.27,4,13.75,13.75,0,0,1-12.25,0A10.76,10.76,0,0,1,83,30a10.76,10.76,0,0,1,5.81-9.73,13.75,13.75,0,0,1,12.25,0,11.16,11.16,0,0,1,4.27,15.47Zm10.54-2.56A5.56,5.56,0,0,0,118,35.31a6.3,6.3,0,0,0,3.16.78,7.77,7.77,0,0,0,3.28-.71V29.49h5.37v8.9a13.94,13.94,0,0,1-4.23,2,16.88,16.88,0,0,1-4.79.7,12.72,12.72,0,0,1-6.08-1.43,10.58,10.58,0,0,1-4.23-4A11,11,0,0,1,108.91,30a11,11,0,0,1,1.54-5.77,10.54,10.54,0,0,1,4.26-4,13.14,13.14,0,0,1,6.17-1.43,13.79,13.79,0,0,1,5.4,1,10.4,10.4,0,0,1,4,2.92l-3.86,3.5a6.82,6.82,0,0,0-5.22-2.4A5.79,5.79,0,0,0,115.05,30,6.51,6.51,0,0,0,115.82,33.13Zm32.84,7.56h-6.08V19.21h6.08Zm24.76,0h-5l-9.48-11.44V40.69h-6V19.21h5l9.48,11.45V19.21h5.95Z"/></a></svg>
 </div>
 <div id="destinies">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291.47 59.84"><defs><style>.cls-6{fill:#ffffff;}</style></defs><a href="destinies.html"><path class="cls-6" d="M79.37,24H75.53V35.78h3.84a6.2,6.2,0,0,0,4.43-1.57,5.63,5.63,0,0,0,1.67-4.32,5.66,5.66,0,0,0-1.67-4.33A6.24,6.24,0,0,0,79.37,24Z"/><path class="cls-6" d="M0,0C21.41,17.25,32.22,36.75,33.49,59.9l240.17-.11A17.83,17.83,0,0,0,291.47,42V-.13ZM90.11,35.57a10,10,0,0,1-4.24,3.74,14.22,14.22,0,0,1-6.26,1.32H69.45V19.15H79.61a14.22,14.22,0,0,1,6.26,1.32,10,10,0,0,1,4.24,3.74,10.58,10.58,0,0,1,1.5,5.68A10.58,10.58,0,0,1,90.11,35.57Zm21.94,5.06H94.8V19.15h16.85v4.69H100.82v3.62h9.54V32h-9.54v3.92h11.23Zm19.37-3a7.25,7.25,0,0,1-3.23,2.5,12.9,12.9,0,0,1-5.21.94,19.91,19.91,0,0,1-5.07-.65,12.74,12.74,0,0,1-4-1.71l2-4.49A13.46,13.46,0,0,0,123,36.33c2.33,0,3.5-.58,3.5-1.75a1.45,1.45,0,0,0-1-1.36,18.49,18.49,0,0,0-3.21-.94,30.42,30.42,0,0,1-4-1.12,6.8,6.8,0,0,1-2.79-1.92,5.16,5.16,0,0,1-1.17-3.56,6.12,6.12,0,0,1,1.08-3.54,7.07,7.07,0,0,1,3.2-2.5,13.09,13.09,0,0,1,5.23-.92,18.29,18.29,0,0,1,4.18.47,12.65,12.65,0,0,1,3.62,1.4l-1.87,4.51a12.47,12.47,0,0,0-6-1.66,5,5,0,0,0-2.64.54,1.61,1.61,0,0,0-.82,1.4,1.38,1.38,0,0,0,1,1.29,17.82,17.82,0,0,0,3.16.88,29.81,29.81,0,0,1,4.07,1.13,7,7,0,0,1,2.79,1.9,5.06,5.06,0,0,1,1.18,3.54A6.08,6.08,0,0,1,131.42,37.62ZM152.19,24h-6.56V40.63h-6.08V24H133V19.15h19.24Zm8.35,16.67h-6.08V19.15h6.08Zm24.77,0h-5l-9.48-11.45V40.63h-5.95V19.15h5l9.48,11.44V19.15h6Zm10.37,0H189.6V19.15h6.08Zm21.58,0H200V19.15h16.85v4.69H206v3.62h9.55V32H206v3.92h11.24Zm19.36-3a7.22,7.22,0,0,1-3.22,2.5,12.92,12.92,0,0,1-5.22.94,19.83,19.83,0,0,1-5.06-.65,12.54,12.54,0,0,1-4-1.71l2-4.49a13.53,13.53,0,0,0,7.09,2.12c2.34,0,3.5-.58,3.5-1.75a1.44,1.44,0,0,0-1-1.36,18,18,0,0,0-3.2-.94,30.42,30.42,0,0,1-4-1.12,6.83,6.83,0,0,1-2.8-1.92,5.21,5.21,0,0,1-1.16-3.56,6.11,6.11,0,0,1,1.07-3.54,7.16,7.16,0,0,1,3.21-2.5,13.06,13.06,0,0,1,5.23-.92,18.26,18.26,0,0,1,4.17.47,12.71,12.71,0,0,1,3.63,1.4l-1.88,4.51a12.43,12.43,0,0,0-6-1.66,5,5,0,0,0-2.64.54,1.62,1.62,0,0,0-.83,1.4,1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1,1.29,18,18,0,0,0,3.17.88,29.63,29.63,0,0,1,4.06,1.13,6.82,6.82,0,0,1,2.79,1.9,5.07,5.07,0,0,1,1.19,3.54A6,6,0,0,1,236.62,37.62Z"/></a></svg>
 </div>
</div>
 <div id="brand">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 106 106"><defs>
    <style>.cls-1{fill:#ffffff;}</style>
    </defs><a xlink:href="index.html"><path class="cls-1" d="M67.78,52.28a5.58,5.58,0,0,0-6,0,6,6,0,0,0-2.11,2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0,7.42,6,6,0,0,0,2.11,2.45,5.58,5.58,0,0,0,6,0,6.05,6.05,0,0,0,2.11-2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0-7.42A6.05,6.05,0,0,0,67.78,52.28Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M53,0a53,53,0,1,0,53,53A53.06,53.06,0,0,0,53,0ZM77.67,78.67a10,10,0,0,1-4.3.91A13.53,13.53,0,0,1,69.14,79a12.7,12.7,0,0,1-3.74-2.09,34.09,34.09,0,0,1-4.26-4.15A13.74,13.74,0,0,1,55.34,70a14.09,14.09,0,0,1-3.91-5A15,15,0,0,1,50,58.44L50,45.66,43.86,55.92H39.69L33.61,46.1V58.44H25v-28h7.77L41.9,45.34,50.79,30.4h7.77L58.6,45a15.72,15.72,0,0,1,6.2-1.21,15.38,15.38,0,0,1,7.6,1.88,13.68,13.68,0,0,1,5.27,5.24,15,15,0,0,1,1.91,7.56A14.78,14.78,0,0,1,77.3,66.6a13.64,13.64,0,0,1-6.17,5.24,3.52,3.52,0,0,0,1.14.9,3.13,3.13,0,0,0,1.29.26,4.94,4.94,0,0,0,3.63-1.81L81,76A9,9,0,0,1,77.67,78.67Z"/></a></svg> 
 </div>
 <div id="reserve">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 944.38 115.07">
 <defs><style>.cls-2{fill:#ff7800;}</style></defs>
 <a xlink:href="reserve.html"><path class="cls-2" d="M494.41,80.8h-3.78v7h3.78a4.7,4.7,0,0,0,3.15-.91,3.23,3.23,0,0,0,1.07-2.59,3.27,3.27,0,0,0-1.07-2.61A4.65,4.65,0,0,0,494.41,80.8Z"/><path class="cls-2" d="M400.62,80.8h-3.77v7h3.77a4.73,4.73,0,0,0,3.16-.91,3.23,3.23,0,0,0,1.07-2.59,3.27,3.27,0,0,0-1.07-2.61A4.68,4.68,0,0,0,400.62,80.8Z"/><path class="cls-2" d="M940.67,10a55.59,55.59,0,0,0,3.71-10H535.66A63.67,63.67,0,0,1,474,59.85h-3.54A63.67,63.67,0,0,1,408.72,0H0A55.59,55.59,0,0,0,3.71,10H364.28V20H9.42a68.63,68.63,0,0,0,8.32,10H364.28V40H30.75C40.78,45.88,53.9,50,71,50H364.29V98.82a16.24,16.24,0,0,0,16.25,16.25h183.3A16.25,16.25,0,0,0,580.1,98.82V50H873.4c17.08,0,30.2-4.12,40.23-10H580.1V30H926.64A68.52,68.52,0,0,0,935,20H580.1V10ZM404.92,99.48l-4.36-6.39h-3.71v6.39h-6.8v-24h11a13.71,13.71,0,0,1,5.66,1.08,8.75,8.75,0,0,1,3.8,12.37,8.38,8.38,0,0,1-3.49,3l5.19,7.55Zm29.84,0h-19.3v-24h18.85V80.7H422.19v4h10.68v5.08H422.19v4.4h12.57Zm21.67-3.36a8.25,8.25,0,0,1-3.61,2.79,14.55,14.55,0,0,1-5.84,1,22.23,22.23,0,0,1-5.66-.72,14,14,0,0,1-4.47-1.92l2.23-5A14.38,14.38,0,0,0,442.83,94a14.06,14.06,0,0,0,4.19.65c2.61,0,3.91-.65,3.91-2a1.62,1.62,0,0,0-1.11-1.53,21.14,21.14,0,0,0-3.59-1,35.84,35.84,0,0,1-4.54-1.25,7.63,7.63,0,0,1-3.12-2.15,5.79,5.79,0,0,1-1.31-4,6.84,6.84,0,0,1,1.21-4,8,8,0,0,1,3.59-2.8,14.69,14.69,0,0,1,5.85-1,20.9,20.9,0,0,1,4.67.53,14.31,14.31,0,0,1,4.05,1.57l-2.09,5a14.06,14.06,0,0,0-6.66-1.85,5.63,5.63,0,0,0-3,.6,1.79,1.79,0,0,0-.92,1.56,1.55,1.55,0,0,0,1.09,1.45,20.1,20.1,0,0,0,3.54,1,34.24,34.24,0,0,1,4.55,1.25,8,8,0,0,1,3.13,2.13,5.72,5.72,0,0,1,1.32,4A6.8,6.8,0,0,1,456.43,96.12Zm23.62,3.36h-19.3v-24h18.86V80.7H467.48v4h10.68v5.08H467.48v4.4h12.57Zm18.65,0-4.36-6.39h-3.71v6.39h-6.8v-24h11a13.71,13.71,0,0,1,5.66,1.08,8.42,8.42,0,0,1,3.71,3.09,8.5,8.5,0,0,1,1.31,4.73,8.41,8.41,0,0,1-1.22,4.55,8.32,8.32,0,0,1-3.49,3L506,99.48Zm24.62,0h-6.7l-10.26-24h7.34l6.53,15.66,6.66-15.66h6.73Zm31,0H535v-24h18.85V80.7H541.76v4h10.68v5.08H541.76v4.4h12.57Z"/></a></svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to make the button labelled Reserve to be fully clickable?

Comment: If you add `background:black` to the body you'll see that the MQ button is not in the center

Comment: Also you can move `reserve` before `brand`

Comment: Thanks for answering "krsna", though my problem was with the mq button.
"enxaneta" moving the divs around was the problem, i didn't knew that could affect it. Also, you're right, i gotta fix the positioning (shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for everything.